# Google Map doesnt work in Bootstrap UI Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I use the Bootstrap Tabset to wrap up Bootstrap slider and Google Map and other pages
however, the slider works fine but google map doesnt work properly, but it work perfect in street view
The googlemap code work perfectly from the other page
What would be the error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you found out what was causing this, Any luck getting nearer a solution? UI Tabs tend to have problems in requesting ajax scripts like maps, share buttons etc

Answer (score 0):

I had recently the same issue. It seems the map is not well loaded because it cannot calculate the size correctly.

I solved it by creating the map once the tab is first displayed. Example:

```
var _map = null;

$('#imap').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if (!_map) {
        // here initialize the map
    }
});
```

where **#imap** is the DIV id and **'shown.bs.tab'** is the bootstrap event when the tab is shown